# Etymology of Mecca

Tags: etymology, history, historical-change, toponyms

Most dictionaries just list it as "from Arabic", with the better ones providing the script مكة or a transcription showing that it's actually pronounced *M**a**kkah* in classical and modern standard Arabic.

To its credit, [the OED notices the problem](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/mecca_n?tab=etymology) but then [handwaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-waving) it with

> the spelling with *e* probably represents a colloquial Arabic pronunciation

So I know this is troublesome to figure out when the main authorities are ignoring the problem, but what *is* the actual etymology of English *M**e**cca*? Is it via French, Italian, or Latin? Is it adaption of Ottoman Turkish *M**e**kke*, the language of the area's overlords when England first started really paying attention to the place? or which "colloquial" (=regional) Arabic is it, Egyptian or something else? or is it a holdover from Old or Middle English that the dictionaries are missing?

Comment: Is it a problem? In cut-glass RP, *Makkah* would sound like *Mecca.*

Comment: There's a vast amount of variation in spelling words from Arabic - look at the number of spellings of Muhammad. Partly this is because of variation in pronunciation of Arabic, and partly because the vowels don't necessarily map well to English vowels. [Islam has been known in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_in_England) for well over 1000 years, and there's a lot published on how it was written about. But this sort of question "why is it spelt X rather than Y?" never really has a factual answer - you can say who spelt it X or Y but not why one was preferred.

Comment: Sure thanks for stopping by but obviously that's untrue/hyperbolic. _Colour_ and _centre_ are both specifically (mis)spelled in British English owing to French. _Stamboul_ has an _m_ because of its old local pronunciation. _Xi'an_ and _Beijing_ are from a precisely dated Chinese government edict in the 1950s. Etc. etc. etc. It may be extremely _hard_ to answer this question given the usual authorities' silence but there certainly _is_ a factual answer to it.

Comment: The easiest way of thinking about this is to focus on the fact that written Arabic has never had vowels.  That is not completely so, since there is a letter pronounced like the modern Greek  'U' (Υ) (as  the 'ee' in cheese).  It seems to have been the ancient Greeks who introduced vowels into the Phoenician alphabet they took over.  But  it is possible to think of vowels as the shortest oral route from one consonant to the next.  The name of the founding father of Islam is a case in point.  It gives a lot of scope for different accents among separate groups of speaker.

Comment: @lly I love the way you say that English people mis-spell their English. They are the English spellings. And the French for colour is *couleur*.

Comment: The names in other languages suggest that the vowels may have changed historically: most European languages seem to use a variant of *Mecca/Mekka* though there seems to be a suggestion Greek has shifted from *Μάκεχ* to *Μέκκα* while Malay seems to be moving from a more traditional *Mekah* towards *Makkah*.

Comment: @Henry ... or that the intermediary language between classical Arabic and most European languages was something else, yep. That was the question.

Comment: The obvious intermediate language would have been Byzantine Greek, thought it had various versions.

Comment: @Henry I wouldn't think so. Western Europe was generally pretty awful at any form of Greek until the collapse of the empire and Renaissance. Still, yeah, I can easily imagine several etymologies too with the "most likely" being Egyptian Arabic which tends to turn (e.g.) standard Arabic "al-..." into "el-..." The question was about if anyone knew or could find out what the _actual_ answer is, though.

Comment: @lly - I suspect the existence of the city was well known throughout Europe by the First Crusade in the 11th century, and probably well before: King Offa of Mercia had gold copies of dinars with (mirrored) Arabic minted in the 8th century.

Answer (score 1):

The OED gives the following attestation dates:

> Mechei (1524), Mæcha (1594), Mecha (1601), and Mecca (1599)

I'm not familiar with any Old English form.

Here is an [Italian book from 1547](https://books.google.com/books?id=TV48AAAAcAAJ&q=Mecca#v=snippet&q=Mecca&f=false) that uses "Mecca".

Searching the [Corpus Corporum](https://mlat.uzh.ch/browser/13988) for Latin attestations, I found *Mecca* only in Johann Jacob Hofmann's *Lexicon Universale* of 1698: "Mecca et la Mecque, urbs Arabiae, Mecca, Mariaba".  The hypothesis of Latin as an intermediary does not seem too likely in light of this.

I think the hypothesis of Turkish as an intermediary seems plausible, but I also cannot find details about the transmission of the name.

Comment: Not an answer but a solid note including a source I didn't know about. I'm not sure how full that corpus is, though. Surely some form of Mecca was entering Latin by the time of the Crusades. I'm picking up _Mecha_ in 1576 and _Meccha_ in 1156. (_Macca_ and _Maccha_ unhelpfully return n.d. entries.)

Comment: @lly: It is certainly not a complete corpus of Medieval Latin, but it has a number of major Christian Latin texts of the Middle Ages.